# Loop through Excel Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Code and I would like it to run in 25 other sheets of the Workbook and instead of repeating the code 25 times,for each sheet is there a way to make it loop?

Can someone assist?

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
Dim lRow As Long

strSearch = "ressort"

Set ws = Sheets("01,02,03")

With ws
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row




    With .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
      .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
      .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$65536").AutoFilter Field:=1

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wrap the processing code in a loop

```
for each ws in thisworkbook.sheets
    ' do something on each worksheet
next
```

example

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim lRow As Long

    strSearch = "ressort"

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If (ws.Name <> "Sheet1") And (ws.Name <> "Sheet2") And (ws.Name <> "Sheet3") Then
            With ws
            lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                With .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
                  .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
                  .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                End With
                ws.Range("$A$1:$P$65536").AutoFilter Field:=1
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

so now if the sheet names are Sheet1 or Sheet2 or Sheet3 they will be skipped.

Comment: Can I add an exception ? I have 3 sheets that I don't want the macro to run on.

Comment: @adp sure let me quickly adjust the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your code will need to be stored in a module, rather than being contained in a sheet.  The following illusrates how the loop works:

```
Sub test()

Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
For Each sheet In Sheets
    thisSheet.Cells(1, 1) = 1
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, can I make it ignore other sheets? I have 3 sheets that I don't want it to run on.

Comment: Yes - you can use thisSheet.CodeName or thisSheet.Name to get the name of the sheet (careful, the two names may be different).  Once you've got the name of the sheet you can use an if statement to filter out the three sheets you don't want it to run on.