# Loop Excel VBA script Through Worksheets Not Functioning

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I 'borrowed' and pieced together code from various SO and other forum posts to create an Excel VBA script in a master workbook which will:

- Wipe the original destination cells 'clean'
- Ask user to choose a source workbook
- Select and copy a range of cells from the source
- Paste in to master workbook in the next open row

This code functions - for one source worksheet only - and is as follows:

```
Sub Copy_Data_Test()

Range("A2:N750").ClearContents

'Set primary variables
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("SIS Agregate")
With WS
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row + 1
End With

Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim vFile As Variant

'Set copy destination
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'Request to open copy source
vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsx", _
    1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
'Exit if no copy source chosen
If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open vFile

'Set copy source variable
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

'Select range to copy
wb2.Worksheets("032_Laguna_Hills").Select
Range("A2:M100").Select
Selection.Copy

'Paste in Copy Destination
wb.Activate
wb.Worksheets("SIS Agregate").Range("A" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

My goal is to have this loop through approx. 50 worksheets. To do this, I found a [suggestion from this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422356/excel-macro-loop-through-excel-sheets) to use a For Each/Next loop to cycle through worksheets and copy the same range of cells.

I am attempting to wrap the processing code, as suggested, with no success. The macro halts when it hits this loop. What I have done wrong or where I have misplaced this code? (I have included only the changed code past opening the source workbook).

```
'Set copy source variable
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws2 = Worksheet

'Select range to copy
For Each ws2 In wb2.Sheets
Range("A2:M100").Select
Selection.Copy

'Paste in Copy Destination
wb.Activate
wb.Worksheets("SIS Agregate").Range("A" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Next ws2

End Sub
```

No error text is provided; the VBA debugger opens with yellow highlights at either `Set ws2 = Worksheet` or `For Each ws2 IN wb2.Sheets` so it seems the problem is early on, but not sure what to do about it. I'm also concerned I'm not swapping between work*books* correctly and this could also be a problem.

Comment: remove `Set ws2 = Worksheet` and maybe add `ws2.Select` after `For Each ws2 In wb2.Sheets`, but I suggest to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select

Comment: Making progress. I removed `Set ws2 = Worksheet`. Some progress is made however, I am now only getting the information from the last worksheet in the source. I have simplified the last bit of code to:`'Select range to copy
For Each Worksheet In wb2.Sheets
Range("A2:M100").Copy

'Paste in Copy Destination
wb.Activate
wb.Worksheets("SIS Agregate").Range("A" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Next Worksheet

End Sub`

Comment: you should select your sheet: `ws2.Select` just after `For Each ws2 In wb2.Sheets` line.

Comment: Forgive my dense-ness. I added `ws2.Select` after that line and received an error 91, Object Var or With block var not set.

Comment: replace `For Each Worksheet In wb2.Sheets` with `For Each ws2 In wb2.Sheets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this likely isn't the cleanest method but until I can refine this it is working solidly for 50 sheets. I used the suggestions above to properly iterate the last row within the loop.

```
Sub Copy_Box_Data()

Range("A2:N5000").ClearContents

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("SIS Agregate")
With WS
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row + 1
End With

Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim vFile As Variant

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsx", _
    1, "Select One File To Open", , False)

If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open vFile

Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

For Each sh In wb2.Worksheets
    sh.Range("A2:M200").Copy
    wb.Activate
    wb.Worksheets("SIS Agregate").Range("A" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set LastCell = wb.ActiveSheet.Cells(wb.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `Set` ws2, just `Dim` it.  The `For Each` does the Setting.

Comment: OKay. I have removed the ws2 variable and it appears to be at least running. However, I am only getting the last worksheet in the source to copy over. I think the loop is copying on each worksheet before it's making any pastes...

Comment: @UserUnknown, well I noticed that "LastCellRowNumber" isn't getting incremented in your code.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing the obvious, this is new for me. I think I was doing that up at the top of my primary code block with `With WS
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row + 1`

Comment: OK, I was just reading your second block of code, but your problem is that you're incrementing it outside of the `For Each` loop, so it never changes in the loop.