# Code to be run on multiple specific sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I want to run a code on multiple sheets. The sheet names are: Sheet1, Sheet2, 1, 2 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 and Summary. I define my sheets of interest= (1, 2, 3, 4 and Summary). The code should run only on these sheets. If any sheet in sheets of interest is not present, it should run for all other sheet of interest, i.e. if 1,2 are not present it should run for 3,4 and Summary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel Macro : loop through Excel Sheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422356/excel-macro-loop-through-excel-sheets)

Comment: BTW, you question is not very clear. Could you give some examples?

Comment: Ok, I will make it clear. Suppose a workbook contains following sheets: Sheet1, Sheet2, 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5......12, Summary. Now, I want the code to run for 1, 2, 3, 4 and Summary. If any sheet out of 1, 2, 3, 4 and Summary doesn't exist, the code should be able to run for other sheets(If 2, 3 are not present, the code should run for 1,4 and Summary). I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: So you want to run your code for every sheet except sheets with the name  `"Sheetx"` where `x` is a number?

Comment: No, I want to run it for the sheet name I can store somewhere. Like if sheetname= 1, 2, 3, 4 and Summary, then run for every sheet found out of these sheets.

Comment: I'm sorry your explanation just doesn't make sense to me so i'm out.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try last time. Workbook: Sheet1, Sheet2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 and Summary are sheet names. Now, if I define my desired sheets= (1, 2, 3,4 and Summary), then it should run only for 1, 2, 3, 4 and Summary even if any of the sheets in my desired sheet is not present. If 2,3 is not present my code should run for the rest, i.e. 1, 4 and Summary.

Answer (score 1):

you can `loop` each sheets into your workbook

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws As Worksheet, a As Range
Sub forEachWs()

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Call yourcode
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic question and you should find the answer by simply Googling it. Though [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/142126) combined with [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) is the answer for you.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer
     Dim found As Integer
     Dim index As Integer
     Dim sheetnames {"1", "2", "Summary"}



     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For I = 1 To WS_Count
         found = 0;

        For index = 0 To numbers.GetUpperBound(0)
            If sheetnames(index) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name Then
                found = 1
            EndIf
        Next 

        If found = 1 Then

            ' Insert your code here.
            ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
            ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
            MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name
        EndIf

     Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: sorry we posted in the same time

Comment: @Fabrizio No problem here ;)

Comment: This won't work if there are other sheets in the workbook. Suppose the sheets are "Sheet1", "1", "2", "4", "5", the code should run for only 1,2,4 and 5.

Comment: Was writing the same - the only difference between mine and @Fabrizio is the IsNumeric - the DIM line should also be inside the procedure unless you want the variable available to all procedures within the module - I'd also replace DIM with PRIVATE to make it available to that module, or PUBLIC to make it available to all modules.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I don't think you should comment this on my answer but on the one of Fabrizio

Comment: @CuriousLad is this what you want?

Comment: No, it shows error on index as variable not defined.

Comment: @CuriousLad Well you should define it then :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to For...Next Loop this will work on all worksheets that are numbered:

```
Sub AllSheets()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Or any workbook.worksheets reference:                   '
    'For Each wrkSht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets            '
    'For Each wrkSht In Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Worksheets   '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        If IsNumeric(wrkSht.Name) Then
            'Your code here.
        End If
    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

---

As a complete alternative you could put the required sheet names in a range in the workbook, give the range a defined name and use this:

```
Sub All()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    For Each rCell In Range("MyDefinedSheetNameRange")
        If WorkSheetExists(rCell.Value) Then
            Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(rCell.Value)
            'Do stuff with wrksht
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub

Public Function WorkSheetExists(SheetName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)
        WorkSheetExists = (Err.Number = 0)
        Set wrkSht = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: See, my point is if I store the name of sheets somewhere, the code should run for all the sheets that exist irrespective if the sheet is numbered or have some name. Can you help with that?

Comment: If you want all worksheets then use @Fabrizio which will reference all worksheets irrespective of the name, mine will work on just numbered.

Comment: I think you didn't get what I asked clearly. Suppose there is a workbook containing sheets named as : Sheet1, Sheet2, 2, 3, 4, 5, Summary. So, if I run the code it should run on 2, 3, 4, 5 and Summary. The name of the sheet I want the macro to run can be stored somewhere. Even if any of the sheet does not exist, the code should run for other sheet whose name is stored.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If sht.Name <= 12 Then
     '
     '
     'MsgBox sht.Name
    End If
Next
```

Comment: A good answer should include some explanation of the code to show how it solves the problem presented in the question.  This answer is nothing but a few lines of code with no explanation.  Consider expanding this answer to show how it solves the problem as described,