# repeat a macro for all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Format()

Dim LastRow As Long

Columns("A:E").Select
Range("A3").Activate
Columns("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Rows("7:7").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("B16").Select

LastRow = Range("D9").End(xlDown).Row
Cells(LastRow + 1, "D").Formula = "=SUM(D9:D" & LastRow & ")"

End Sub
```

I am working on sheet that require reporting to individuals with different quantity of data tables with same structure. What if I need to repeat the code for all worksheets. I am follower of stackoverflow and learn so many things from this forum.

Thank You
Keshav

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Excel Macro -How to repeat the macro for each sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316523/vba-excel-macro-how-to-repeat-the-macro-for-each-sheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through sheets

```
Sub Format()

    Dim LastRow As Long, sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In Sheets
        With sh
            .Columns("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
            .Rows("7:7").Delete Shift:=xlUp
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(LastRow + 1, "D").Formula = "=SUM(D9:D" & LastRow & ")"
        End With
    Next sh
End Sub
```

### Loop through sheets except one

```
Sub LoopSheetsExceptOne()
    Dim LastRow As Long, sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets(1)

    For Each sh In Sheets

        If sh.Name <> ws.Name Then

            With sh
                .Columns("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
                .Rows("7:7").Delete Shift:=xlUp
                LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                .Cells(LastRow + 1, "D").Formula = "=SUM(D9:D" & LastRow & ")"
            End With

        End If

    Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: What if the same needs to be exclude for Sheet Index 1

Comment: I have added an additional code to skip the first sheet

Comment: Superb :) Thank You Davesexcel

Comment: I am trying to export all worksheets (except Shee1) to pdf to a predefined folder with predefined name. It is saving all the worksheets. The problem is i need to save the excel table till last data row of worksheet to pdf only.

Comment: Sub ExportToPDFsQ()
     ' PDF Export Macro
     ' Change C:\Exports\ to your folder path where you need the diles saved
     ' Save Each Worksheet to a separate PDF file.
 
     Dim ws As Worksheet
 
     For Each ws In Worksheets
     ws.Select
     nm = ws.Name
 
     ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
     Filename:="C:\Users\Keshav\Desktop\TSPL\" & nm & Format(Now, " DD-MM-YYYY") & ".pdf", _
     Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
 
     Next ws
 
     End Sub

Comment: You should start a new thread, the original question has been answered