# Rearrange columns on all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the code pasted below working for one worksheet in the workbook but I can't figure out how to loop it through the workbook so it does it to every sheet.

Can someone explain how to use to loop function for this code please? :)

```
Sub Rearrange_Columns()
Dim arrColOrder As Variant, ndx As Integer
Dim Found As Range, counter As Integer
arrColOrder = Array("Company", "First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "Category", "Address", "Suite or Unit?", "Suite/Unit", "City", "Province", "Postal Code", "Phone", "Fax", _
"Website", "Service Areas", "Logo", "CONCAT")
counter = 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For ndx = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)
    Set Found = Rows("1:1").Find(arrColOrder(ndx), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole,SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        If Found.Column <> counter Then
         Found.EntireColumn.Cut
         Columns(counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
     End If
Next ndx
End Sub
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422356/loop-through-excel-sheets#20422491) should be useful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through Excel Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422356/loop-through-excel-sheets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is just a loop through the worksheets, and specify the worksheet for each `Rows`, `Columns`, `Range`, etc

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Rows(…) 'specify the worksheet
Next ws
```

For Example

```
Option Explicit

Sub RearrangeColumnsInAllWorksheets()
    Dim arrColOrder As Variant
    arrColOrder = Array("Company", "First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "Category", "Address", "Suite or Unit?", "Suite/Unit", "City", "Province", "Postal Code", "Phone", "Fax", "Website", "Service Areas", "Logo", "CONCAT")

    Dim ndx As Long
    Dim Found As Range

    Dim Counter As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'loop through all worksheets
        Counter = 1
        For ndx = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)
            Set Found = ws.Rows("1:1").Find(arrColOrder(ndx), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Found Is Nothing Then
                If Found.Column <> Counter Then
                    Found.EntireColumn.Cut
                    ws.Columns(Counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End If
                Counter = Counter + 1
             End If
        Next ndx
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'don't forget to turn it on again
End Sub
```

Comment: This one moves all of my data on each different sheet to the right. My last sheet, sheet 86 I think, starts in column BAQ, when it should start in A1!  Any ideas? :O

Comment: Fixed counter reset and moved `Counter = 1`.